# find command behaves weird on AIX

Tags: find

Found something weird with the find command on AIX 7.1. I executed find command to list files of specific permissions. It works when I execute as below

```
find . -type f -perm 600 -exec ls -la {} \;
```

But fails to pull the files when I execute as below

```
find /user -type f -perm 600 -exec ls -la {} \;
```

Is anyone familiar with this kind of error?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `/user` a symlink? Then `try find /user/ ...`

Comment: I guess that is a link. But what difference would it make?

Comment: That's how find(1) works, nothing  AIX-specific.